# T-SQL, SSRS: Set up automatic daily Inserts into Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

SSMS 11.0.6248.0.

I want to create an automated way of Inserting data [using a T-SQL insert statement] into a SQL Server table before users start using the system [third-party business system] each morning.

I do a lot of SSRS reporting and creating subscriptions; know how to do inserts using T-SQL, and I am familiar with stored procedures, but I have not had to automate something like this strictly within SQL Server.

Can I make this happen on a schedule - strictly in the SQL Server realm [i.e. using SSRS ... or a stored procedure ... or a function]?

Example Data to read:

```
Declare @t Table 
(
DoctorName          Varchar(1),
AppointmentDate     Date,
Appointments        Int
)

Insert Into @t select 'A','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'B','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'C','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'D','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'E','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'F','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'G','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'H','2018-10-23', 5
Insert Into @t select 'I','2018-10-23', 5;

Select * From @t
```

The value in Appointments changes through the day as Doctors see patients. Patients may cancel. Patients may walk in. Typically, at the end of the day Doctors end up seeing more patients than they have scheduled at the start of the day. [I set the number at 5 for all Doctors at the start of the above day].

I want to capture the data as it is at the start of each day - before the Clinic opens and the numbers change - and store it in another Table for historic reporting.

I hope this simplified example clarifies what I want to do.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how I might **best** go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the SQL Server Agent.  A more specific suggestion will require a more detailed description of what you're doing (with sample data, preferably).

Comment: It does, assuming that you're actually writing to a table in your database and not to a table variable.  If that's the case then you can absolutely use the [SQL Server Agent] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017) to do this.  Note that this link is to the current version; for running a simple series of insert commands 2012 will behave the same.

Comment: Is it possible to Add an Insert Statement to an existing SSRS report that is already running daily so that it not only produces the report, but also starts inserting the output for the report into the table that I need it to reside in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS to create a job that you can then schedule.  Since you are familiar with stored procedures, you would create your SP first then in SSIS add a Control Flow of **Execute SQL Task** and configure it according to your needs.

If that doesn't work for you, you could create an application to run on a Timer that executes your SP, however, since you want to stay in the SQL realm, SSIS is the place to look.

Comment: Thanks! I will be providing more detail [with sample data] so that more specific suggestions can be made.